# Simple js inject code with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "rabbi",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "something",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.1.min.js", "rabbi.js"],
      "matches": [ "http://*.facebook.com/*", "http://facebook.com/*", "https://*.facebook.com/*", "https://facebook.com/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
     "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs", "http://*.facebook.com/*", "http://facebook.com/*", "https://*.facebook.com/*", "https://facebook.com/*" ]
}
```

and rabbi.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

     alert("Thanks for visiting!");

 });

</script>
```

But a message "Thanks for visiting" never pops up when I enter facebook.

Comment: the jquery is there from my extension the other one isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting a script, not a html document. So you don't need the `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag.

as a side note: With the property `"run_at": "document_end"` your script is injected when the DOM is completely constructed.  Which is  in fact at the same time `$(document).ready` fires. This means you don't necessarily need to wrap your code inside this function.

Comment: Indeed, I just saw that abraham also answered this in his comment

Comment: The first part of this answer is distracting nonsense: `$(document).ready()` behaves fine, even if the document has already loaded. The last part of the answer solves the problem, starting a JavaScript file wiht `<script>` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

you specified that you should run your script at `"run_at": "document_end"` this is after the dom ready event has fired (so you don't need it)

Answer (score 0):

`rabbi.js` is a JavaScript file so you can remove the HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Thanks for visiting!");
});
```

Comment: That didn't help.. still no message

Comment: Since you are running the `content_script` at `document_end` you may not need the `ready` trigger. Try just the `alert` line.

Comment: Keep in mind that Facebook uses ajax to load pages so it will only fire on initial page loads or if you refresh the entire page.